# How to handle JWT both bearer and refresh token in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Getting reponse after login as {"token": "dfd.mxyz.kym", "type": "bearer", "refreshToken": "abc.xyz.123"}

we are passing token received, in request header for following request steps->
Authorization: Bearer dfd.mxyz.kym

but sample result from jmeter display as following:
Response code: 401
Response Message: Unauthorized
Response headers:
HTTP/1/1 401 Unauthorized

Request suggestion on ways to handle the above issue

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract the token from the response using i.e. [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide) configured like:

   [image]
2. Make sure that the `token` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) has the anticipated value using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)

   [image]
3. Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) as a child of the next request and configure it as follows:

   [image]
4. Your request should be successful now.